# How do I compile more than one .asm file with fasm into one output?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I want to compile multiple assembly files in fasm. 
I have some instructions in the one file and other instructions in the other file. How do I link these files to a binary output ?

And may I use extern in this case ? Or is this an illegal command ?

Comment: Yes, use `extern` and a linker.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to compile multiple assembly files in fasm.

So you have multiple .ASM source files.

- Select one of your source files as the main source file.
- Insert in it an `include` preprocessor directive for every additional source file that you want in your single binary output file.
- Assemble. No linker required, FASM does it all.

Example with 3 source files

```
; Main source is 'source1.asm'
include 'source2.asm'
include 'source3.asm'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally create an includes file (much like a header for my application) and simply include that file which lists all files to be "included".

```
include 'includes.inc'
```

The *includes.inc* will then, itself, have all the relevant inclusions listed for a "project style" structure.

This is an alternative approach to [what Fifoernik states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351828/how-do-i-compile-more-than-one-asm-file-with-fasm-into-one-output/47352618#47352618) (which is correct).

I also like to externalize data segments as well (especially when developing for Windows) into *vars.inc* (read & write permissions, no execution) and *const.inc* (read only with no write or execution permissions). Something else to ponder on a side note.